# 550 Can't change directory to public/storage: No such file or directory filezilla

Tags: php, laravel, filezilla, online-storage

i host my laravel site `aswaktinghir.ma`, i tried to add a user with these images, the insertion was done with success, but the profiles images are not showing, and i don't know if images and forward to root `public\ storage \ profiles \ October2020`, and when I want to open the storage folder in fillezilla, to see if there are any images to insert, it gives me error `550 Can't change directory to /public/storage: No such file or directory` knowing that it works well locally.

**RegisterControllers.php**

```
  if($request->hasFile('image'))
       {
        $image = $request->file('image'); 
        //crypt image and rename the image/s by its root
        $imagee = md5($image);
        $image->storeAs("aswakfolder\public\profiles\\".$jdate->format('F').$jdate->year,$imagee.'.'.$image->extension());
        $user->image = "aswakfolder\\public\\storage\\profiles\\".$jdate->format('F').$jdate->year."\\".$imagee.'.'.$image->extension(); 
        }
        $im = $user->image;  
        //images
        $dataim = array();
         if($request->hasFile('images')) 
         {
            foreach($request->file('images') as $file) 
            {
                $namee = md5($file->getClientOriginalName()).'.'.$file->extension();
                $name = "aswakfolder\public\storage\profiles\\".$jdate->format('F').$jdate->year."\\".$namee;
                $file->storeAs("aswakfolder\\public\\profiles\\".$jdate->format('F').$jdate->year, $namee);  
                array_push($dataim,$name);
            } 
         }
```

Comment: Did you do `php artisan storage:link` yet? This creates a symbolic link for the public storage folder.

Comment: @RobinHeller thx for u answer ,yes I have already created a symbolic link online, and when I want to see the content of this folder (storage) it gives me error

Comment: What's the environment? Single server? Shared hosting? Is this running on a Windows server, since you're using backslashes?

Comment: @RobinHeller I'm sorry because I'm a beginner, I don't know but hosting is web linux Cpanel ,but my project is with windows

Comment: You can search for image files using Filezilla (search for the file's name), then you can find out where the images are uploaded (if at all). Mixing Linux and Windows for development setups can be a tough setup for a beginner.

Comment: @RobinHeller Yes exactly

Comment: Try to use DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR constant so either OS can interpret it instead of using backslash?